# random function in sql

Tags: sql, function

How I can make function random to data of school schedule in this schedule we have table for teacher it has (teacher id ,teacher name and subject id),table for subject it has (subject id and subject name ) ,table for day it has (day id and day name),table for lecture  it has (lecture id ,lecture name , subject id and day id )

Comment: Can you write sample code and expected output.

Comment: I can not do this function code because I am at the beginning to learn I want from you help me to do it the schedule will be for sixth level in the school I want make the schedule in each run be order in random with out repeatation

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Random what? Integer values, or float, or characters, or timestamps or...

Comment: String values like mathmatic and science ....

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear about what is your expected output.But simply you can try this for mySql.

```
SELECT column FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified.

Comment: I have project the output of project is information about what lectures the student have  in the day for example class six has math in first lecture ,class six has social-worker in second lecture ... and I want to make this information order of random with out repeatation ,do you understand me

Comment: The type of the output data is varchar2

Answer (score 0):

Check the below SQL query for random selection of string data,

```
    select Subjects from School_Schedule ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Comment: I do this answer but the result is unvalid

Comment: without seeing your table structure it is hard to give exact answer. Can you update your table structure and data in question.